# Custom control not binding in lightswitch html client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm building an HTML 5 client app and am having trouble databinding to a custom control. I have a lightswitch query called EDWParam based on an externally populated table that has two columns: Parameter_Name and Parameter_Value. This table is updated every five minutes via an external process. How can I bind my custom control so that when the parameter value changes, the custom control is refreshed? I've tried

contentItem.dataBind("value.Parameter_Value")

in the post render method for the control but the value never refreshes without pressing F5. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use:

```
setInterval(function, milliseconds);
```

setInterval will call the 'function' once every 'milliseconds'.

All you need is a function that will update your screen data.  You could call the LightSwitch DataSource, a restful webservice, or refresh the screen using this function.